# I accidentally delete zsh from /bin folder in Mac

Tags: macos, zsh

I delete the zsh binary from bin folder , so when i try to change my shell i get this :

> chsh: WARNING: shell '/bin/zsh' does not exist

I don't know how to reinstall zsh shell and MacOs come with zsh by default.

Comment: Time Machine backup maybe?

Comment: Grab it from here: https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh , and repeat the installation process, you setting should be preserved.

Comment: @uraimo There are no instructions on how to install (never mind restore) *zsh* on *Oh My Zsh's* GitHub page. *Oh My Zsh* **is not** the same as *zsh*. *Oh My Zsh* is just a set of configuration files for *zsh*. Re-installing (or installing, the OP never said that he uses *Oh My Zsh*) will not restore a deleted. Also, the installation process of *Oh My Zsh* specifically requests that the configuration directory is removed if it already exists. So settings will not be preserved without some work on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed that problem using mac tools. I invested only about 30 min of my time whith the reinstall option. It's obviously there is a way to generate a zsh binary, but I find easy reinstall the osx due to Osx come by default with the zsh binary and brew install doesn't install the zsh binary. On the other hand, there must a way to install zsh from scratch but I think find the correct way would take more time

Comment: `brew install zsh` or `brew reinstall zsh` must install the `zsh` binary to `$(brew --prefix)/bin/zsh`, unless your Homebrew install is broken. The binary is independent from system `zsh`. Please don't mislead other users.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing would be to install zsh using `brew` (which will install it in `/usr/local/bin/zsh`) and then symlink it to `/bin/zsh`.

There are obvious more ways to fix this, but this seems (to me) to be the simplest.

Comment: I can't do that because zsh is already installes, if i do that i get this : `Warning: zsh-5.0.7 already installed `, I think the only way is reinstall zsh again but aparently there a lot file to remove so I need a command with bre w for uninstalling it

Comment: @uraimo it is `uninstall` e.g. `brew uninstall zsh && brew install zsh`?

Comment: yes, remove was the old way to do this, use uninstall.

Comment: thanks for the answers, I tried this brew commands, but they doesn't generate the `zsh binary`  located in  `/bin` since `zsh binary`  come installed by default with Osx Yosemite. I think there'll  be  a way to generate this binary with a new installing from scratch